# How convert parameter filter[smth]=1 in retrofit

Tags: retrofit, retrofit2

I have hard request from php with parameters
&filter[type]=1&filter[id]=2
but i don't understand how how can i convert such parameters? Oo

Comment: It's a bit vague what your asking. Convert to what exactly and what do you already have?

Comment: parameters in the query look like this &filter[type]=1&filter[id]=2
And i don't understand how can i write custom convert for it :(

Comment: But why do you need a custom converter? Wouldn't a `@QueryMap` work? I mean, I'm happy to provide an example using this, but I just want to understand if you tried it already and for any reason discarded it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided to write an answer using `QueryMap` because I think it's a viable solution and it's one I've been using.

Retrofit has an annotation called [@QueryMap](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/index.html?retrofit2/http/QueryMap.html). As the name suggests, it let's you pass a Java map which will be serialized as query parameters. I think this could be used in your example. Imagine the following Retrofit interface:

```
interface MyApi {
  @GET(SOME_PATH)
  Call<MyModel> get(@QueryMap Map<String, String> parameters);
}
```

Now what we can do is call it like so:

```
HashMap parameters = new HashMap();
parameters.put("filter[type]", "1");
parameters.put("filter[id]", "2");
myApi.get(parameters);
```

*Here, `myApi` is an instance of the Retrofit proxy for your api*

What will happen is that Retrofit will serialized the query parameters like you want.

Comment: Thank. I didn't think of anything better either